# How can I move around in the Vim command line?

Tags: vim

If you're typing a command in Vim (I mean you've started with `:` and you're working in the bar at the bottom of the screen) is there a way to move the cursor around other than tapping the arrow keys? In particular, can you move it to the beginning, end, back n characters, or back one word?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Type

`:h cmdline-editing`

for details.  I am listing a few of the interesting non-arrow commands that do something similar to what you want.

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd>: cursor to beginning of command-line
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd>: cursor to end of command-line
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd>: delete the word before the cursor
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd>: remove all characters between the cursor position and the beginning of the line

Comment: Thanks, that's great. I searched through that help doc and I'm not seeing a way to move back and forth by word. Do you know if that's available?

Comment: The documentation says that shift+left and shift+right are used to move back and forward a word.  It also has an example of how to bind `<Esc>b` to shift+left (and so on) in commandline mode: `:cnoremap <Esc>b <S-Left>`

Comment: That key mapping looks aweful lot like Emacs :)

Comment: If you want your Vim command line editing to be more like Emacs or Bash, see the remappings in `:help emacs-keys`

Answer (score 123):

Tap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> while in command-line mode (just after `:`). There you'll get command-line window which could be edited&navigated as a regular vim window (hjkl etc.).

See `:h cmdline-window` for details.

Comment: And `Ctrl-C` exits.

Comment: This is a gem.  `:q` also seems to get you out of it.

Comment: If only you could get tab completion inside the command-line window!

Comment: Nice, but it seems to have other drawbacks e.g. it breaks insertion of the current filename with `Ctrl+R` `%` and inserts `[Command Line]` instead.

Answer (score 33):

To add to Maxim Kim's Answer,

In the `Normal Mode` ..

`q:` -> cmdline window for commands

`q/` -> cmdline window for search forward

`q?` -> cmdline window for search backward

`Ctrl-C` or `<CR>` will take you out of cmdline-window

Comment: Some of the time, my one hand unintentionally beats the other and I inadvertently end up typing `q:` instead of `:q`. Took me ages to figure out what I was typing to end up in the strange command window (at least it was intuitive how to get out of it).

Comment: After `q:` cmdline window for commands open up. You can scroll through the commands (hjkl) and `<CR>` will execute the one you are currently at. `<Ctrl-C>` can be used to edit the current command you are at. You can also edit any command from within the window by going into the Insert mode (press i inside the cmdline window), editing a command and then pressing `<CR>`

Answer (score 26):

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>left arrow</kbd>: move back a word
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>right arrow</kbd> - move forward a word
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> - back to the beginning of the line
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> - go to the end of the line
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> - remove one word before the cursor
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> - remove line
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> - if you need more editing power use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> and you will edit your command in normal mode. For example, if you want to move 5 characters to the left, use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> and then `5h`.

Comment: On Mac `Ctrl + left arrow` moves the entire desktop. I disabled it but `Ctrl + left arrow` moves the cursor to the left of the line.

Comment: `ctrl+shift+left/right arrow` works for me on macos with iterm2.

Comment: you can also ctrl+h to erase the previous char, though this could depend on shell, not sure.

Answer (score 5):

You can actually add your own movement keys. For example, I use the following in my .vimrc to make moving around the command mode finger-friendly in an hjkl way (abusing the ctrl key):

```
 " moving aroung in command mode
 cnoremap <c-h> <left>
 cnoremap <c-j> <down>
 cnoremap <c-k> <up>
 cnoremap <c-l> <right>
 cnoremap ^     <home>
 cnoremap $     <end>
```

where **^** and **$** are really < ctrl-^ > and < ctrl-$ > respectivelly, typed as < c-v >< c-^ > and  < c-v >< c-$ > in the .vimrc (for some reason < c-^ > and < c-$ > won't work, at least in my setting, but the former do)

Answer (score 4):

On Mac OS,

- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>left arrow</kbd>: move back a word
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>right arrow</kbd>: move forward a word

Answer (score 3):

`nnoremap q; q:` to facilitate typing. usr_20.txt and cmdline.txt contains all useful infos.

Comment: after that `q;` accomplish the same `:` then `<C-f>`