# Navigating in Vim's Command Mode

Tags: vim, text-editor, vi

I am a long time emacs user learning Vim. Emacs lets me navigate in the mini-buffer (where I issue commands like C-x C-s) using the same navigation keyboard shortcuts as in any other buffer. For example, I can navigate forward one character using C-f, even while in the mini-buffer. I could also use the arrow keys, but they are too far away.

Is there any keyboard shortcut to navigate in Vim's command mode (:), without using the arrow keys -- equivalent to emacs C-f, C-b? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I move around in the Vim command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075569/how-can-i-move-around-in-the-vim-command-line)

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Adding to Greg Hewgill's answer, you can use `q:` to open the command-line window, where you have any Vim editing power at your hand.

Comment: When I have learned one thing about Vim, then that you never stop learning some new and amazing feature ;-)

Comment: Also if you're already on the command line and you want to keep what you've written and still go into the command-line window, type ctrl-F. Thus ":<C-F>" should accomplish the same thing as "q:". If it doesn't work, than either 'compatible' is set or you have some other key mapped to the 'cedit' option. See :help q: for more details :)

Comment: this command was one on of my most annoying commands. Now it's one of the most useful one :)

Comment: Why can't I paste the '"%' register when using 'q:' or ':<C-f>' and I can only using the normal ':' ?

Comment: Literally spent years being annoyed whenever this would pop up unexpectedly.  Now I know what it does and I love it!

Comment: To make this default: `nnoremap : q:i`

Answer (score 50):

Some from the Vim help:

```
CTRL-B or <Home>
        cursor to beginning of command-line
CTRL-E or <End> 
        cursor to end of command-line
CTRL-H              
<BS>        Delete the character in front of the cursor (see |:fixdel| if
        your <BS> key does not do what you want).
<Del>       Delete the character under the cursor (at end of line:
        character before the cursor).
CTRL-W      Delete the |word| before the cursor.  This depends on the
        'iskeyword' option.
CTRL-U      Remove all characters between the cursor position and
        the beginning of the line.
```

Answer (score 36):

I have these in my .vimrc

```
cnoremap <C-a> <Home>
cnoremap <C-e> <End>
cnoremap <C-p> <Up>
cnoremap <C-n> <Down>
cnoremap <C-b> <Left>
cnoremap <C-f> <Right>
cnoremap <M-b> <S-Left>
cnoremap <M-f> <S-Right>
```

Comment: This makes me so happy. For users with issues bind `<Meta>` see http://stackoverflow.com/a/27206531/1213041

Comment: I've found that aligning Vim command-mode and shell bindings, especially if you're using Vi bindings, works well. I'd refine the above great suggestion to avoid overwriting existing useful bindings; for example, `C-f` since that's usefully bound to "edit current line in command-mode in buffer". `^b` in command-mode in Vim is already bound to (Emacs-like) `<Home>`, and `^a` clashes with `screen(1)` (and for lots of people, `tmux(1)`).

Answer (score 11):

With the default key bindings, vim does not offer non-arrow-key navigation of the command line editing. However, see `:help cmdline-editing` for an example of how to use the `:cnoremap` command to set up alternate key bindings.

Answer (score 2):

I achieved that with `<C-p>` and `<C-n>` to navigate previous and next commands respectively.

P.S I'm not making any custom binding like [Tassos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/173715/tassos) did.