# Move forward/backwards one word in command mode?

Tags: vim, vi

Lets say I am copying a file with the vim command mode and my cursor is at the end of the line.

```
:!cp path/to/original/file path/to/new/file
```

Is there a way I can jump back a word like I can in the shell by typing `Esc b`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot use "Esc b" because, obviously, that would discard the command you where typing. However you can bind some keys to move around.

The question as already be answered here : [Navigating in Vim's Command Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920943/navigating-in-vims-command-mode)

The easy way is just to add :

```
cnoremap <C-a> <Home>
cnoremap <C-e> <End>
cnoremap <C-p> <Up>
cnoremap <C-n> <Down>
cnoremap <C-b> <Left>
cnoremap <C-f> <Right>
cnoremap <M-b> <S-Left>
cnoremap <M-f> <S-Right>
```

In your .vimrc

Comment: Great thanks. By the way, the second link in your answer just links back to this question.

Comment: My bad, I pasted the wrong link. And I lost the first one now... To bad.

Answer (score 3):

A nice vim feature is `ctrl-f`.   Typing `^f` (or whatever key is specified in the `cedit` option, with `ctrl-f` being the default) from command line mode has the same effect as typing `q:` from normal mode; it pulls your entire command history into a window and lets you edit it as a buffer.  Try `:help cmdwin` for more details.

Comment: `q:`, not `:q` -- that might be a mistake!

Answer (score 2):

For entering and editing complex commands, you may like working directly in the command line window which is accessed with the normal mode command `q:`.  See `:h 20.5` and `:h q:`.  Or if you are already in command mode, you can access the command line window with `C-f`.

- For example, in normal mode type `q:` to get into the command line window. (or type `C-f` from command line mode.
- You can move around previous commands using standard motions and you can edit as usual.
- When you want to execute a command that you just edited, press `enter` in normal mode in 
  this command line window.  The line your cursor is on will be executed as a command in
  the window you were in before you opened the command line window.

Another option to consider is to edit/yank the command from another buffer. You can do this by yanking the desired text and pasting it in command mode by typing `C-R n`, where `n` is the register you yanked to.

BTW: I like the mappings that @rks provided.  But if you don't have these mappings, you can use the out of the box commands. Look up `:h c_<S-Left>` and `:h c_<S-Right>` and `:h 20.1`.

Answer (score 0):

In vim's command mode, I just use ctrl-left and ctrl-right arrows.  The same works in bash - I wasn't aware of the esc-b method there.

No editing of the .vimrc file is required for this on my Ubuntu and Debian systems, but YMMV on others.  It's presumably based on the standard configuration that's packaged for the OS