# moving quickly in the command line of vim

Tags: vim, vi

While using **vim** sometimes I encounter some cases where I need to correct the command (substitution for instance) or **pipelined commands** and where I need to go back everytime to correct some characters or to add something by using the **arrow keys** which is a little bit annoying.
I found some combination like 
`ctrl-u` which clear all the command or `ctrl-w` which clear every word .

But do you know any combination that will let me jump quickly through the **command line** like `0`, `$`, `b`, `w`, `e` do ?

Thanks !

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075569/how-can-i-move-around-in-the-vim-command-line

Comment: Thanks @dNitro ! I found what I was looking for ! :)

Comment: @dNitro **personally** I won't use those combination. well I am not telling they are bad. Because, in terminal I am using emacs mode without arrow-keys  to edit  commandline. `c-u, c-w, c-h, c-f, c-b,alt-w...` those are very common, however when I use those in vim commandline mode, I will automatically change to shell-commandline edition .. and press ctrl-f ctrl-b...c-b does emcas c-a and worse is ctrl-f, it brings me to cmdline-window, and later keystrokes happen in that window (normal mode) I am surprised everytime.... it is very annoying

Comment: @Meninx, Glad it helps ;) .

Comment: @kent, admit it. but why emacs-mode and not vi-mode; what we use on a daily basis?!

Answer (score 3):

You should enter the command-line window.
Press `Ctrl-F` in command mode (or `q:` in normal mode).  You will enter the command-line window. There you can edit your commands just as in vim.

Check out `:h q:` for details.